# Android Google Playstore Upload Rejection for SMS permission policy violation issues

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, android-permissions, google-play-console

We are trying to publish the android app into play store but first time, the app got rejected for default handler SMS permission.

again, we declared form and given necessary information at policy declaration app content place, the still not accepted.

our requirement is needs to filter our customer READ_SMS to scrubbing and populate into application.

how are we handle it. if google not accepted READ_SMS permission, we want to proof to customer to convenience the SMS features not possible to delivery. i could see across internet, we could not find the any strength of answer. hence, we can use SMS permission or not.

we are waiting for you all valuable advise.